# Align figure to the right (with \raggedleft) while still centering its caption with respect to the image

Tags: horizontal-alignment, floats, captions, wrapfigure

I am wondering if it is possible to align an image to the right margin of the page (with `\raggedleft`) while still having it's caption nicely centered (with `\centering`) under the image (centered with respect to the image itself I mean, not w.r.t the page).

Is this possible in latex?
Ideally the solution should work within both a `figure`and `wrapfigure` environments.

Comment: The standard LaTeX document classes are all set to center a "short" caption (i.e., a caption that fits on a single line) *irrespective* of what you do with the rest of the floating environment's contents.

Comment: Maybe I should have specified that I use the caption package: `\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=centering,belowskip=0pt]{caption}`

Comment: In that case you should be all set for `figure` floats: the captions will be set centered regardless of whether you use `\centering`, `\raggedleft`, or whatnot for the rest of the `figure` environment. Not sure if this is also true for `wrapfigure` environments -- it may depend on how large the indented graphic is relative to the `\linewidth` parameter. Not knowing how these parameters are set in your code, I can't be more specific.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your input. I will look into it ASAP :). If it does not solve my problem I will provide a MWE to bring some clarity.

Comment: I have a feeling that @GonzaloMedina's answer is better than mine; I may not have understood correctly that you need the caption to be centered on (and no wider than) the right-justified float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can simply use a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
  \raggedleft
  \begin{minipage}{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{name}
  \caption{Some caption that spans more than a line and some additional text}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to decrease the space between figure and the figure caption. after insert the ps figure and its figure caption, both seem to far apart.